# rails devise recaptcha prepend_before_action :check_captcha not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, recaptcha

What's happening is users are able to sign in even when captcha verification fails Here's my routes concerning users:

```
      devise_for :users, controllers: {
        sessions: 'users/sessions',
        registrations: 'users/registrations',
        passwords: 'users/passwords'
      }
    resources :users
```

Here's my relevant app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb  code:

```
    prepend_before_action :check_captcha, only: [:create]
    
        def check_captcha
          return if !verify_recaptcha # verify_recaptcha(action: 'login') for v3
    
          self.resource = resource_class.new sign_in_params
    
          respond_with_navigational(resource) do
            flash.discard(:recaptcha_error) # We need to discard flash to avoid showing it on the next page reload
            render :new
          end
        end
```

My config/rechaptcha.rb contains environment checks and passes different keys depending on environment:

```
    Recaptcha.configure do |config|
      if Rails.env.development?
          config.site_key  = '6L..Bg'
          config.secret_key = '6L..WG'
      elsif Rails.env.production?
          config.site_key  = '6L...b'
          config.secret_key = '6L.gy'
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method returns from the callback if the captcha fails and continue action

`return if !verify_recaptcha`

So you need rewrite it to something like this

```rb
def check_captcha
  unless verify_recaptcha
    self.resource = resource_class.new sign_in_params
    respond_with_navigational(resource) do
      flash.discard(:recaptcha_error)
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Still get the same unwanted behavior On page refresh the user is logged in Fill in email and password fields and leave recaptcha unchecked and click submit; first time desired behavior; now refresh page, undesired behavior, the user is signed in and a flash notice says  You are already signed in. This is really nuts

Comment: I didn't mean refresh I meant click on submit once more and the user is signed in without recaptcha verification

Comment: This is weird. Can you please attach logs after you click submit (first and second)?

Comment: Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected

Comment: I got it working by changing ```render :new``` to ```redirect_to new_user_session_path``` but I'm looking for other syntax's also

Comment: I got it working using `redirect_to new_user_session_path` for logins but I'd rather use "resource" notation instead of explicitly naming the paths but I can't find an example Can you help

Comment: Why do you want these changes? Your controller is not universal, but only for the User (`users/sessions`). So it's normal to have there `new_user_session_path`. But if you want I think it might be reached with `polymorphic_path` helper `new_polymorphic_path([resource_class.name.downcase.to_sym, :session])`

Comment: Just meant a redirect I can put in all 3 controllers instead of having to name the actual paths I though it could be done with "resource" notation

Comment: Also I don't understand why ```only: [:create]``` is used for passwords_controller I would think it should be ```only: [:update]``` wouldn't you?